# Introduction to topology in modern (categorical) language?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, reference-request, category-theory

Have studied traditional point-set topology, but find there's a fairly large gap between the preparation typical point-set courses give you, and the level assumed in algebraic topology texts.

Looking for a good introductory book on topology that uses more categorical / modern language - something that would segue smoothly into, for example, Tammo tom Dieck's text Algebraic Topology - at least covering most of the topics mentioned in the first chapter of his book (subspaces, quotients, products, sums, compactness, proper maps, paracompactness, topological groups, transformation groups).

Have perused the MIT textbook 'Topology - A Categorical Approach', which looks decent, but isn't so comprehensive.

Have found one text that looks good (Grundkurs Topologie by Laures and Szymik) - but unfortunately it's in German! (Anyone know of an existing English translation?)

Open to recommendations. Thanks.

Comment: Literally, all of those topics can and should be covered in point set topology. How did you study point-set topology? None of them requires category theory.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I used Metric and Topological Spaces by Sutherland. It's not the content per se, it's the enveloping language used to discuss it. Hard to find something that dovetails.

Comment: Seems like any introduction to homology theory would work. I learned this from Vick, which I like because it’s short.

Comment: @Deane Thanks for the recommendation, I'll take a look

Comment: "Topology and Groupoids" by Brown might be useful.

Comment: Everyone upvoting the first reply, you are misunderstanding the question.